# Firebase real time database simple select query extremely slow

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

**EDIT** : After commenting the `orderByChild`, the request seems actually faster but still takes around 15 seconds to complete.

Below is the beginning of a function I use to retrieve orders from a Firebase realtime database. It is a function located inside my Cloud Functions index.js file :

```
function updateStatsForDay(db, day_moment, cronSpeed, devOnly) {

  console.log('updateStatsForDay START', cronSpeed, devOnly);
  const today = day_moment.hours(0).minutes(0).seconds(0).milliseconds(0).format('YYYY-MM-DD');

  return db.ref('/orders')
    // .orderByChild('event_start_date').endAt(today)// Prevent listing events in the future
    .once('value', snapshot => {
      console.log('updateStatsForDay orders retrieved');
```

This table `orders` has about only 300 rows, but this simple query takes sometimes up to 40 seconds to retrieve them (the time spent between the 2 console logs). I tried commenting the `orderByChild` filter thinking it might be the problem but the request remains very slow.

Is there something I am missing here?

Here is an example of an order in the database :

[image]

This table as the following rules:

```
"orders": {
      ".indexOn": ["uid", "event_start_date"]
    },
```

Comment: I don't immediately see anything in that code that would cause the query itself to be slow. How much data are you pulling down (to see if it could be related to bandwidth instead of query speed)?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I am not sure how to get this information, but after exporting the full orders table, I got a 598KB JSON file.

Comment: "Sometimes up to 40 seconds". What if you run it twice in a row, is it faster on the second run? Because if your functions aren't used for a while, they can take a while to spin up again. Although 40 seconds for just getting this amount of data (although it's much, not _that_ much) is still weird..

Comment: @funkizer In my development environment, this function is executed every minute in a cron, so it should not be the problem here.

Comment: I also don't find anything in particular that could cause the slow time for the queries, but I can suggest you to follow [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/optimize) documentation that talks about optimization in the RTDB

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your data structure but if it has nested data that might be an issue and you might want to re-structure it to be as flat as possible.

From firebase documentation:

> Because the Firebase Realtime Database allows nesting data up to 32
> levels deep, you might be tempted to think that this should be the
> default structure. However, when you fetch data at a location in your
> database, you also retrieve all of its child nodes. In addition, when
> you grant someone read or write access at a node in your database, you
> also grant them access to all data under that node. Therefore, in
> practice, it's best to keep your data structure as flat as possible.

Reference: [Firebase: Best practices for data structure](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data)